# What does "is its own" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, phrase-meaning

In general I do not understand the usage of "is its own" in a sentence. A sentence containing "is its own" immediately becomes unclear to me. For example what does "is its own" mean in the following context?

> since the hand of a clock is its own clearly definable concept, it is a good idea to create it an own class - BoundedCounter

Because a concept is an idea, my interpretation of the above sentence is that **something (in this case the hand of a clock) is its own idea so it is a good idea to create a class for that something** but that doesn't make sense so may be my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: *If some thing....is its own idea, then it is prudent to create a class for that thing.

Comment: The "its own" adds nothing to the meaning. It is just saying that "the hand is [by itself] a clearly definable concept."

Answer (score -1):

You are right. The sentence is a poor one, and "is its own" is incorrect.

The correct usage is when an object provides some function for itself. For example:

> An artillery piece requires a vehicle to move it around the battlefield. But a self-propelled gun **is its own** vehicle.

A better rendition of your sentence is:

> since the hand of a clock is a clearly definable concept, it is a good idea to create its own class.

Comment: The source of this sentence appears to be an online course from the University of Helsinki. The English is generally excellent but there are a few places where it is slightly unidiomatic.

Comment: “Is it’s own” would definitely be incorrect, but it doesn’t say that. “Is its own”, which it does say, is not incorrect by any standard I can imagine. “The hand is its own clearly definable concept” means exactly the same as “The hand is a clearly definable concept unto itself”. The latter is more idiomatic to me (and I would guess probably to most English speakers), but the former is by no means _incorrect_. On the other hand, “it is a good idea to create it an own class” **is** ungrammatical; “to create a separate class for it” would be how you’d normally phrase that in English.

Comment: Thanks all, @JamesRandom (your deduction is correct). It's all much clearer now but since the hand of a clock is something not an idea (i.e. a concept) should it not be "the concept of a hand of a clock is a clearly definable concept" instead of "the hand of a clock is a clearly definable concept"? The latter implies that something is a concept but how can something be a concept when something is concrete where as a concept (i.e. idea) is abstract.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet , I couldn't tag you in my previous comment but that question is for you too, I would appreciate your thoughts

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to be that explicit. It is quite clear what is meant when someone says, "A house is a concept that..." It would be unnecessarily redundant, otiose and a tautology to say "The concept of a house is a concept that ..."

Comment: @JamesRandom , thanks for clarifying that "the hand of a clock" is referring to the concept not the object, in that case then "since the hand of a clock is a clearly definable concept" makes perfect sense. The reason for my misunderstanding was that there is the object and then the concept of the object so I guess explicitly stating which one would leave no room for confusion or doubt. Off-topic, since you're familiar with the source of the quote, have you completed both part I and II of the MOOC?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree that the sentence shown is NOT ungrammatical. Some confusion may derive from the OP's wording of the question title, because they make it sound as if *is its own* were a complete syntactic constituent -- like a copula with predicate complement. The result fails to scan only because that truncates the NP before its head, orphaning the non-substantive elements from their mandatory substantive to create nonsense. But reappend *concept* to reconstitute the fragmented constituent and all will be syntactically wholesome once again.

Comment: @Janus 'The latter is more idiomatic to me (and I would guess probably to most English speakers), but the former is by no means incorrect'  surely indicates something approaching the acceptable/unacceptable divide. Svartvik and Greenbaum have established that acceptability grey areas exist. Here, I'd say that '[is] its own', being as user323578 says redundant, is merely a source of likely confusion, a breach of Gricean maxims. // 'since the hand of a clock is a clearly definable concept in its own right ...' is idiomatic.